# Drain vs vent. How to determine which is which

Tags: plumbing

I have a roughed in plumbing for an outdoor kitchen. Curious how I can tell which is for the drain and the vent? Picture below
[image]

Comment: One pipe seems to have something written on it, maybe you got lucky and plumber labelled it.

Comment: No writing on either

Comment: the upper one is the vent, it is always above the drain

Comment: The pipe on top seems to have something that looks like a Y, F in marking pen on it just below the cap.

Comment: @crip659 those look like regular pipe marking, not hand written

Comment: @Ruskes  The pipe marks are fainter.  These were done with a sharpie/permanent marker.  Odd to enhance a couple of pipe markings on one pipe.

Comment: @crip659 granted, you have better eyes than me

Comment: Presumably the pipe caps are not glued on, so pull that one off (or both of the middle ones) and see if there is something written there.

Comment: I'm confused how either could be a properly installed vent - a vent shouldn't run horizontal until it's 6" above the spill line of the highest fixture it serves. Here, the top pipe is barely 6" above the drain height, much less the spill line.